# unable to find gradle dependency for zephyr -ZFJCloudRestClient

Tags: gradle, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api, jira-zephyr

I am new to ZAPI and generating the JWT token through java code for authentication.

I got the code for generate JWT token from :https://github.com/zephyrdeveloper/zapi-cloud/blob/master/Samples/src/com/thed/zapi/cloud/sample/sampleJwtGenerator.java

i was not able to resolve couple of imports

```
import com.thed.zephyr.cloud.rest.ZFJCloudRestClient;
import com.thed.zephyr.cloud.rest.client.JwtGenerator;
```

Can someone pleasse help me which gradle dependencies do i need use to get use to get this resolved.

Thanks

Comment: did you found any answer for this? I am also stuck on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702943/rao

Comment: may be this will help you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298900/how-to-generate-jwt-token-for-jira-api

Answer (score 0):

I download the jar from here which solved my issue: https://github.com/jenkinsci/zephyr-for-jira-test-management-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/zfj-cloud-rest-client-3.0.jar